# Python Input and Output?

Tags: python, input, output

I am working on learning python and I for some reason the output I get is always incorrect. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it and any help is greatly appreciated:

```
##a.    3 variables —
##  The name of a movie
##  The number of tickets to purchase
##  The total cost of tickets purchased
##
##b.        1 Constant —
##  The cost of a single ticket
##2.    Create four print statements that will display the values of the variables and the constant along with labels that describe them
##

#Initialize
movieNm = str("")
numTickets = int(0)
totalTicketPrice = float(0.0)

SINGLE_TICKET = int(10)

#input
name = input("Enter the name of the movie you would like to see:")
numTickets = input("Enter the number of tickets you wish to purchase:")


#process
totalTicketPrice = SINGLE_TICKET * numTickets


#output
print("Feature Film", name)
print("Cost of single ticket", SINGLE_TICKET)
print("Number of Tickets purchased", numTickets)
print("Your Total", SINGLE_TICKET * numTickets)
```

When you test the code the output is always just so wrong and I'm not sure how to fix it. thanks!

Comment: `str("")`, `int(0)` etc are entirely redundant. Just `""`, `0` etc is entirely sufficient to initialize a string and an int respectively.

Answer (score 1):

in this line `numTickets = input("Enter the number of tickets you wish to purchase:")` when you got user input you got `string` you should convert this input to `int` like below:

```
numTickets = int(input("Enter the number of tickets you wish to purchase:"))
```

see this example maybe help you *(this example happen in your code)*:

```
print('2'*10)
# 2222222222
```

Comment: I just tested this, still not working unfortunately. Any other ideas on what could be causing the issue?

Comment: @vex The define *what* “isn’t working” exactly. What do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: @vexxedenigma run this code and got error again? explain what is your error?